# Serialise entire Page tree to JSON in EpiServer

Tags: c#, json, episerver

I am completely new to EpiServer and this has been killing me for days :(

I am looking for a simple way to convert a page and all it's descendents to a JSON tree.

I have got this far:

```
public class MyPageController : PageController<MyPage>
{
    public string Index(MyPage currentPage)
    {
        var output = new ExpandoObject();
        var outputDict = output as IDictionary<string, object>;

        var pageRouteHelper = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EPiServer.Web.Routing.PageRouteHelper>();
        var pageReference = pageRouteHelper.PageLink;

        var children = DataFactory.Instance.GetChildren(pageReference);
        var toOutput = new { };
        foreach (PageData page in children)
        {
            outputDict[page.PageName] = GetAllContentProperties(page, new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }
        return outputDict.ToJson();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> GetAllContentProperties(IContentData content, Dictionary<string, object> result)
    {
        foreach (var prop in content.Property)
        {
            if (prop.IsMetaData) continue;

            if (prop.GetType().IsGenericType &&
                prop.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(PropertyBlock<>))
            {
                var newStruct = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                result.Add(prop.Name, newStruct);
                GetAllContentProperties((IContentData)prop, newStruct);
                continue;
            }
            if (prop.Value != null)
                result.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is, by converting the page structure to Dictionaries, the JsonProperty PropertyName annotations in my pages are lost:

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "MySubPage", GroupName = "MNRB", GUID = "dfa8fae6-c35d-4d42-b170-cae3489b9096", Description = "A sub page.")]
public class MySubPage : PageData
{
    [Display(Order = 1, Name = "Prop 1")]
    [CultureSpecific]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value-1")]
    public virtual string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = 2, Name = "Prop 2")]
    [CultureSpecific]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value-2")]
    public virtual string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

This means I get JSON like this:

```
{
    "MyPage": {
        "MySubPage": {
            "prop1": "...",
            "prop2": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
    "MyPage": {
        "MySubPage": {
            "value-1": "...",
            "value-2": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

I know about using custom ContractResolvers for the JSON serialisation, but that will not help me because I need JSON property names that cannot be inferred from the C# property name.

I would also like to be able to set custom JSON property names for the pages themselves.

I really hope that a friendly EpiServer guru can help me out here!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you update your question to include ToJson implementation as well, one suggestion i would make is to change `Dictionary<string, object>` to `Dictionary<string, MySubPage>`

Comment: I am just using `outputDict.ToJson();` at the end of the Index method. Regarding your suggestion, I could do this I guess: `var newStruct = new Dictionary<string, prop.GetType()>();`

I'm not sure that would help though?

Comment: UPDATE: I'm trying out JOS.Content.Json now. Hopefully this will help. If it does I will post my solution. https://github.com/joseftw/JOS.ContentJson

Answer (score 1):

One of the C# dev's on my project rolled his own solution for this in the end. He used reflection to examine the page tree and built the JSON up from that. Here it is. Hopefully it will help someone else as much as it did me!

```
using EPiServer;
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.DataAbstraction;
using EPiServer.DataAnnotations;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;
using EPiServer.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using EPiServer.Framework;
using EPiServer.Framework.Initialization;

namespace NUON.Models.MyCorp
{
    public class MyCorpPageController : PageController<MyCorpPage>
    {
        public string Index(MyCorpPage currentPage)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/json";

            // check if the JSON is cached - if so, return it
            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            string cachedJSON = cache["myCorpPageJson"] as string;
            if (cachedJSON != null)
            {
                return cachedJSON;
            }

            var output = new ExpandoObject();
            var outputDict = output as IDictionary<string, object>;

            var pageRouteHelper = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EPiServer.Web.Routing.PageRouteHelper>();
            var pageReference = pageRouteHelper.PageLink;

            var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
            var children = contentLoader.GetChildren<PageData>(currentPage.PageLink).OfType<PageData>();
            var toOutput = new { };

            var jsonResultObject = new JObject();

            foreach (PageData page in children)
            {
                // Name = e.g. BbpbannerProxy . So remove "Proxy" and add the namespace
                var classType = Type.GetType("NUON.Models.MyCorp." + page.GetType().Name.Replace("Proxy", string.Empty));
                // Only keep the properties from this class, not the inherited properties
                jsonResultObject.Add(page.PageName, GetJsonObjectFromType(classType, page));
            }

            // add to cache
            CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            // expire the cache daily although it will be cleared whenever content changes.
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1.0);
            cache.Set("myCorpPageJson", jsonResultObject.ToString(), policy);

            return jsonResultObject.ToString();
        }

        [InitializableModule]
        [ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule),
                  typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
        public class EventsInitialization : IInitializableModule
        {
            public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
            {
                var events = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
                events.PublishedContent += PublishedContent;
            }

            public void Preload(string[] parameters)
            {
            }

            public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine context)
            {
            }

            private void PublishedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
            {
                // Clear the cache because some content has been updated
                ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
                cache.Remove("myCorpPageJson");
            }
        }

        private static JObject GetJsonObjectFromType(Type classType, object obj)
        {
            var jsonObject = new JObject();
            var properties = classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public
                | BindingFlags.Instance
                | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var jsonAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a => a is JsonPropertyAttribute);
                var propertyName = jsonAttribute == null ? property.Name : ((JsonPropertyAttribute)jsonAttribute).PropertyName;

                if (property.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BlockData))
                    jsonObject.Add(propertyName, GetJsonObjectFromType(property.PropertyType, property.GetValue(obj)));
                else
                {
                    var propertyValue = property.PropertyType == typeof(XhtmlString) ? property.GetValue(obj)?.ToString() : property.GetValue(obj);
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        propertyValue = propertyValue ?? String.Empty;
                    }
                    jsonObject.Add(new JProperty(propertyName, propertyValue));
                }
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
    }

    [ContentType(DisplayName = "MyCorpPage", GroupName = "MyCorp", GUID = "bc91ed7f-d0bf-4281-922d-1c5246cab137", Description = "The main MyCorp page")]
    public class MyCorpPage : PageData
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm looking for the same thing, and until now I find this page and component.
https://josefottosson.se/episerver-contentdata-to-json/

https://github.com/joseftw/JOS.ContentJson

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned in the comments above I already tried this.

In the end one of our C# dev's rolled a homegrown solution using reflection to build an object that could be serialised nicely. I'll post it below.